# c++/cli List String runs out of memory

Tags: arrays, arraylist, c++-cli

I have List String with tens of thousands elements. My program works fine but from one third of my list program stops taking values and returns nothing. And I don't know why it is doing it? Is it the Code that's bad or has my program just run out of memory. This is my code below:

```
    String^ fileName = "text.txt";
cli::array<String^> ^ myarray = File::ReadAllLines(fileName);
List<String^> ^ words = gcnew List<String ^>();
for (int a = 0; a < myarray->Length; ++a)
{
words->AddRange(myarray[a]->Split(' '))

if (words[a] == UserInput && words[a + 1] == "noun")
{
datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[2]->Value = "noun";
}
}
```

Comment: I believe the way C++ works is whenever a data structure is close to reaching it's capacity (close to being full), it dynamically doubles in size, usually in powers of 2. 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. It may just be a memory issue because you have so many elements. How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: I have 8Gb RAM. I don't see message box with text "run out of RAM" it's just after certain number of elements that it stops returning value. But program still prints element when I manually choosing it's index number e.g: cout  words [360000]

Comment: It's possible that that element may not even exist! What is the size of your list at that point? C++ won't actually tell you if you have run off of your allocated memory..

Comment: I'm 100% sure element exist

Comment: Well, there are some useful tools you can try. You can use a debugger that will step you through line by line and show you exactly what is happening in your code/with the memory. Or you can use some asserts!

Comment: Maybe I should split text file into multiple and create new List String with each one of them ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help, but it might be worth a shot. Again, a debugger is going to be your best friend here, as it will tell you EXACTLY what is going on. If this is helpful, please up vote the comment!

Comment: Use Valgrind massif to perform memory profiling and check for other problems   valgrind --tool=massif yourexe   http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: What exactly are you "returning" when you say it "returns nothing?"  Is it that the `AddRange` call doesn't add anything new?

Comment: e.g. user writes "world" then program goes to array and finds this word and takes the next element, and returns this output "world - noun", but I see an empty cell.

Comment: What cell?  Maybe you need to include more of your program.  For example, when the code you have listed here finishes executing, what is the value of `words->Count`?  What do you expect it to be?  Also, if you want to do the kind of lookup you mention, why not use a `Dictionary` or some other container better suited to the task?

Comment: I' m using datagridview to store my values, and I don't have dictionary that could use.

Comment: Please answer:  What is `words->Count` returning when complete?  Is it what you expect?  You don't show any code involving a datagridview, so that's why I suggested `Dictionary`.